# (Error)SQL CODE -530, ERROR THE INSERT OR UPDATE VALUE OF FOREIGN KEY PAY$ID$U IS INVALID

Tags: sql, db2

The error is coming from the payment table. It says that the insert values for PAY_ID_U are incorrect. What is the problem? The pieces of code below are a portion of the insert values for both tables.
[image: Here are the tables invoice and payment]

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENT                                            
  VALUES('0100','00100','DEBIT','33456A','2021-01-20',1856.54);
INSERT INTO PAYMENT                                            
  VALUES('0110','00110','CREDIT','11223E','2020-02-02',56.78); 
INSERT INTO PAYMENT                                            
  VALUES('0120','00120','NONE','55334Z','2020-12-22',88.99);   

INSERT INTO INVOICE                                                 
  VALUES('0100','00100','TARGET','2019-01-08',100.00,'OPEN');       
INSERT INTO INVOICE                                                 
  VALUES('0110','00110','MORTGAGE','2021-01-20',1856.96,'PAID');    
INSERT INTO INVOICE                                                 
  VALUES('0120','00120','VERSACE','2020-08-20',985.97,'UNPAID');
```

Comment: INVOICE runs smoothly however Payment stops at the first Line because of the Error

Comment: (Error code that DB2 is throwing) DSNT408I SQLCODE = -530, ERROR:  THE INSERT OR UPDATE VALUE OF FOREIGN KEY    
         PAY$ID$U IS INVALID                                                  
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 23503 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE

Comment: Is there anything in the screenshot that we should read? Include the table definition as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 is behaving correctly here, it is saying there is no such invoice key as '00100' (for the first insert into payment).  The reason is your invoice.inv_id is CHAR(5), but when you insert into invoice you specify only four characters in the values statements for the invoice key, missing the leading zero!

By the way, it is good practice to always explicitly name the insert column names.

So change your insert statements as follows, notice the key length is 5 characters:

```
INSERT INTO INVOICE (inv_id, inv_id_u, inv_desc, inv_date, inv_amt, inv_status)
    VALUES('00100','00100','TARGET','2019-01-08',100.00,'OPEN');    


INSERT INTO INVOICE (inv_id, inv_id_u, inv_desc, inv_date, inv_amt, inv_status)
  VALUES('00110','00110','MORTGAGE','2021-01-20',1856.96,'PAID');    

INSERT INTO INVOICE (inv_id, inv_id_u, inv_desc, inv_date, inv_amt, inv_status)
  VALUES('00120','00120','VERSACE','2020-08-20',985.97,'UNPAID');
```